# parTraversable not creating any sparks

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

When I run this program with `-s`:

```
module Main where

import Control.Parallel.Strategies

main :: IO ()
main = do let xs = take 1000 $ product . take 1000 . repeat <$> [1..]
              x  = product (xs `using` parList rseq)
          putStrLn (show x)
```

Sparks are created:

> SPARKS: 1000 (993 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 6 GC'd, 1 fizzled)

If I change `parList` to `parTraversable`

```
x  = product (xs `using` parTraversable rseq)
```

no sparks are created:

> SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

If I change `rseq` to `rdeepseq`:

```
main = do let xs = (take 1000 $ product . take 1000 . repeat <$> [1..]) :: [Integer]
              x  = product (xs `using` parList rdeepseq)
          putStrLn (show x)
```

No sparks are created

> SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

I am using parallel-3.2.1.1 and in the source code, `parList` is defined using `parTraversable` !

```
parList :: Strategy a -> Strategy [a]
parList = parTraversable
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce your behaviour (ghc-8.2.1, parallel-3.2.1.1).

Later on down the `Strategies.hs` is a `RULES` pragma that special-cases `parList rseq`.  I guess it is a bug that it has different behaviour to `parTraversable` (I don't know enough about the internals to be sure where the bug lies).  I'd suggest filing a ticket at the `parallel` issue tracker: https://github.com/haskell/parallel/issues

Here is the code in question, starting at line 505 of the file:

```
-- Non-compositional version of 'parList', evaluating list elements
-- to weak head normal form.
-- Not to be exported; used for optimisation.

-- | DEPRECATED: use @'parList' 'rseq'@ instead
parListWHNF :: Strategy [a]
parListWHNF xs = go xs `pseq` return xs
  where -- go :: [a] -> [a]
           go []     = []
           go (y:ys) = y `par` go ys

-- The non-compositional 'parListWHNF' might be more efficient than its
-- more compositional counterpart; use RULES to do the specialisation.

{-# NOINLINE [1] parList #-}
{-# NOINLINE [1] rseq #-}
{-# RULES
 "parList/rseq" parList rseq = parListWHNF
 #-}
```